# libclt13 no found. What's libclt13?

Tags: configuration, dependencies

I'm configuring an application but keeps telling me that libclt13 is not found. I have no idea what libclt13 is, any ideas?

Comment: Could be anything. Go through the dependencies one by one and see which one is missing.

Answer (score 0):

**CLT13: This is an Implementation of the CLT13 multilinear map specialized for obfuscation purposes.**

https://github.com/5GenCrypto/clt13/releases

Give a try to above link.

*(Though, I am not sure of compiling this will provide the required "libclt13")*